# How to limit aws instance ip range generated by ec2-instance create cli script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, docker, aws-cli

In my jenkins environment, i have configured the AWS cli, which generates the AWS instance on the run using "ec2-run-instances" command. On this i create docker and run it. However, occassionally i need to debug the generated instance manually. Now the issue is that i am working in a secured environment, where access to unknown instances is blocked by default as per corporate security policies. So i could not login to generated aws linux instance.
I want to know, what can be the best way to handle this situation? Is there an option, using which i can specify aws instance would pickup from particular ip range? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking here requires configuration of a VPC - and run all your EC2 instances in it.  A VPC can consist of one or more subnets - and be configured to how an IP range.

During the launch of an EC2 instance (manually or through CLI) - you can specify a subnet.  The new EC2 instance will only come up in that IP range.

Depending on what you need, you can pick the VPC scenario 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenarios.html

(complexity increases from 1-3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! Looks like a potential solution, i will give it a try and come back if need more information.... Best regards